# How to merge two arrays of hashes by the same pair of key and value ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I'm new in ruby. I have two hashes:

```
f = { "server"=>[{ "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10" }, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1" }] }
g = { "admin" =>[{ "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1" },
                 { "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"}]}
```

and I want to get another hash like this:

```
{ "data" => [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10", "name" =>"adam", "mail"=>"any"},
             {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1", "name" =>"mike", "mail"=>"id"}]}
```

The pairs `"hostname"=>"something"` always matches in hashes of both arrays. I have tried something like this:

```
data = server.merge(admin)
```

but it isn't so easy and as you expect it doesn't work. Could you help me merge these hashes and explain for the future how you did it?

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your question. One of the input hashes had an error (`=` should have been `=>`) and I've assigned variables (`f` and `g`) to each input hash so that readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way that i can think of right now will look like:

```
servers = { "server" => [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}]}
admins = { "data" => [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10", "name" =>"adam", "mail"=>"any"}, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1", "name" =>"mike", "mail"=>"id"}]}
# FYI: you can just use arrays for representing the above data, you don't necessarily need a hash.
list_of_entries = (servers.values + admins.values).flatten
grouped_by_hostname_entries = list_of_entries.group_by { |h| h['hostname'] }
grouped_by_hostname_entries.map { |_, values| values.inject({}, :merge) }
#=> [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10", "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any"}, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1", "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code and example**

```
ff = f["server"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["hostname"]] = g }
  #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, "b1"=>{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}}

{ "data"=>g["admin"].map { |h| h.merge(ff[h["hostname"]]) } } 
  #=> {"data"=>[{"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"},
  #             {"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}]}
```

**Explanation**

We want to produce a hash

```
{ "data"=>arr }
```

where

```
arr #=> [{ "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10" },
    #    { "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1" }]
```

so we need only compute `arr`.

First, we create the hash

```
ff = f["server"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["hostname"]] = g }
  #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, "b1"=>{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}}
```

We have

```
enum = f["server"].each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"},
  #                  {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator (and passed to its block) by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, {}],
  #    [{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}, {}]]
```

Note

```
enum.each { |g,h| h[g["hostname"]] = g }
  #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"},
  #    "b1"=>{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}}
```

`each` passes the first element of `enum` and assigns the block variables using *parallel assignement* (also call *multiple assignment*):

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, {}] 
g #=> {"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"} 
h #=> {}
```

We may now perform the block calculation:

```
h[g["hostname"]] = g
  #=> h["a1"] = {"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"} 
  #=> {"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}
```

The return value is the new value of the block variable `h`. The second element of `enum` is then passed to the block and the block calculation is performed:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}, {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}}] 
g #=> {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"} 
h #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}}
```

Notice that the hash `h` has been updated.

```
h[g["hostname"]] = g
  #=> {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}
```

So now

```
h #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"},
  #    "b1"=>{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}}
```

and

```
ff #=> {"a1"=>{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, "b1"=>{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}}
```

Now we can compute `arr`:

```
g["admin"].map { |h| h.merge(ff[h["hostname"]]) }
```

The first element of g["admin"] is passed to the block and assigned to the block variable:

```
h = g["admin"][0]
  #=> {"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1"}
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
h.merge(ff[h["hostname"]])
  #=> h.merge(ff["a1"])
  #=> h.merge({"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"})
  #=> {"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}
```

Then

```
h = g["admin"][1]
  #=> {"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"} 

h.merge(ff[h["hostname"]])
  #=> h.merge(ff["b1"])
  #=> h.merge({"hostname"=>"a2", "ip"=>"10"})
  #=> {"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"a2", "ip"=>"10"}
```

Therefore,

```
arr
  #=> [{"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"},
  #=>  {"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}]
```

is returned by the block and we are finished.

Answer (score 0):

As another variant you can try this

```
h1 = { "server" => [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}]}
h2 = { "admin"  => [{"name" =>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1"}, {"name" =>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"}]}
h1['server'].zip(h2['admin']).map { |ar| ar.first.merge(ar.last) }

#=> [{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10", "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any"}, {"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1", "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id"}]
```

`zip` let us iterate through two or more arrays at the same time.
We use `map` to return result.

In `map` block `ar` would be equal

- `[{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}, {"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1"}]`
- `[{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10.1"}, {"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"}]`

So `ar.first` would be `{"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10"}` and the `ar.last` would be `{"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1"}`

Finally we use `merge` to combine two hashes.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Suppose `h2["admin"].reverse!; h2 #=> [{"name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"}, {"name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1"}]`. Then `h1['server'].zip(h2['admin']).map { |ar| ar.first.merge(ar.last) } #=> [{"hostname"=>"b1", "ip"=>"10", "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id"}, {"hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10.1", "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any"}]`, which is of course incorrect. All is not  lost, however, as you merely need to pre-sort one or both the arrays so they are ordered the same on the value of `"hostname"`.

Comment: Thank for notice. I did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = { "server"=>[{ "hostname"=>"a1", "ip"=>"10" }, 
{"hostname"=>"b1",   "ip"=>"10.1" }] }

g = { "admin" =>[{ "name"=>"adam", "mail"=>"any", "hostname"=>"a1" },
{ "name"=>"mike", "mail"=>"id", "hostname"=>"b1"}]}

# manual way
host_admin_merge = []
host_admin_merge << f["server"].first.merge(g["admin"].first)
host_admin_merge << f["server"].last.merge(g["admin"].last)

# a bit more automated, iterate, test key's value, append to new array
host_admin_merge = []
f["server"].each do |host|
  g["admin"].each do |admin|
    if admin[:hostname] == host[:hostname]
      host_admin_merge << host.merge(admin)
    end
  end
end

# assign the array to a hash with "data" as the key
host_admin_hash = {}
host_admin_hash["data"] = host_admin_merge
p host_admin_hash
```